# Accessing `folder/index.php` by default using `.htaccess`?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I want to make it as default:

from:

`mydomain.com/folder/folder/`

to:

`mydomain.com/folder/folder/index.php`

anyway to do in `.htaccess`?

Comment: You want to show `mydomain.com/folder/folder/index.php` in the address bar instead of `mydomain.com/folder/folder/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This redirects all two level folders from `/f1/f2/` to `/f1/f2/index.php` and shows it in the address bar. It *doesn't* redirect `/f1/f2` or `/f1/script.php` (without a trailing slash)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php   [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/(\w+)/(\w+)/$
RewriteRule .*       %1/%2/index.php               [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @Olaf This solving the problem but now it create another problem: the dynamic content is not presented correctly

Comment: @amir2000 Is the dynamic content presented correctly, when you call directly `mydomain.com/folder/folder/index.php`?

Comment: yes. only when i add the new rules it showing links and not images.

Comment: @amir2000 Please see updated answer, apend `$` to the second `RewriteCond`.